# install "npm install -g ionic@latest cordova" but I get errors

Tags: node.js, bash, cordova, ubuntu, installation

When I run the below command in cordova,

`npm install -g ionic@latest cordova`

I get the following errors -

```
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /ionic/chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.1.2
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-43-Microsoft
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ionic@latest" "cordova"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/npm/node_modules/dezalgo
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/npm/
node_modules/dezalgo'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/
npm/node_modules/dezalgo']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/npm/node_modules/dezalgo' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/oj1125/npm-debug.log
```

Can anyone help me with these errors?

Comment: it worked fine on mine, maybe you need administrator privileges on your computer if you don't have it. @User1125 if you do then there is some programs in the module that are trying to process some stuff that need permisson.

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions